# My android app force closes with toast and action bar search

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toast

I had my app with just an action bar search (not working) load sucessfully on my android galaxy nexus. When I went to actually implement the search, by retrieving the search and making a toast pop up, it crashes on launch.

My eclipse error counsel shows this:

```
06-04 14:33:06.902: D/libEGL(11017): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-04 14:33:06.956: D/libEGL(11017): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-04 14:33:06.987: D/libEGL(11017): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-04 14:33:07.112: D/OpenGLRenderer(11017): Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 14:33:07.237: D/AndroidRuntime(11017): Shutting down VM
06-04 14:33:07.237: W/dalvikvm(11017): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4121c930)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.beerportfoliopro.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:25)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:460)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:822)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:253)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
06-04 14:33:07.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my main where I implement this looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((OnQueryTextListener) this);
                return true;
        }

        //get entered search and pop up a toast to show query entered
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + query + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((OnQueryTextListener) this);
```

here in this line you are trying to cast an activity to your OnQueryTextListener class. this is toally wrong.

Instead of this send a listener object as a parameter

Comment: Awesome, I also needed to change the class to:

implements OnQueryTextListener

Comment: if you implement the listener then just pass this as parameter . @Mike

Answer (score 0):

change your search view code as below.

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```